# Removing junk files from my Android device

Tags: applications, performance

Previously I had installed an application for cleaning junk files from my phone, but the app no longer works with my device.

What is the best way to find and remove junk files from my phone in order to save space and increase performance. Is this something I can do on my own (And if so, how?), or is it best to use an app from the Play Store (And if so, which one?)?

Comment: Well, I can't talk much about maually cleaning things up but what you can do is try installing a app that can be of mutiple user like it will act as app locker, antivirus, call or sms blocker, RAM cleaner, Junk Cleaner etc and it should be small size app, then do one thing try using **360 Antivirus** once stop app which can be founded over the playstore. I have been using it for a while and think it's something which you can give a shot !

Answer (score 1):

-Clearing junk depends on the memory limitations of the device.If you have more memory(4Gb or more then you can avoid it but at some point of time you have to clean) then you don't need to clear the junk files as the device will simply store it on board.But if the device's on board memory is less <=2Gb then you have to clear the junk files quite often.(In case you have 15-30 apps installed then your phone may start responding late/worst case stuck)

-Junk cleaner applications usually clean the cache memory/files >10 Mb as well as the files which are left after uninstalling an application.

So in order to them manually you can follow these steps

-For simple tasks like clearing images/videos you can delete it from the gallery directly as the gallery sorts them based on the app.

-For cache you need to clear the cache separately from app menu.
Only for removing un-instaled app data you need the cleaner.

-Ex:-If you use whats app then you can manually delete the videos/pictures shared from the whats app folder by Videos/Images section.But if you directly delete whats app folder then you will lose all the chat data/backup as well.

**Note**:-If cleaning each and every applications cache is cumbersome then you have to use the cleaner application.Having more on board storage space does not remove the necessity of cleaning it only delays the frequency of cleaning.

**Caution**:-Do not delete any file blindly from your device.Cross check the file name with the existing list of applications.As deleting files may cause loss of data to that particular application.By time you will be able to identify the file structure

Comment: @ user285oo6: So you're suggesting I should use a cleaning app?

Comment: @AaymanKhalid please state your device specifications? also like i said if you are not familiar with the file system then for a safe side go for cleaner app initially once familiar you can delete it all by your self

Comment: @AaymanKhalid check the updated answer

Comment: @ user285oo6: the processor is 1.2 GHz and the internal memory is 4GB.

Comment: well in that case the cleaning app is not required provided you do not have many applications/heavy game applications that take up 1GB space.Just follow the above simple steps to clean and you are better.Clear the cache only once in 1-2 weeks.

Comment: @user285oo6 your first note needs a revision: Boot to recovery, select "wipe cache", wait for the task to finish, reboot, done :) And yes, both stock and custom ROMs support this, no root required.

Comment: @AaymanKhalil I can only second what's already stated: If you're not familiar with the system (and especially with the file system), you're much better off using a good cleaner app. If unsure which to trust: Visit our sister-site [Software Recommendations](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) (before asking there, read the post I've linked – they've got some quality guidelines to be met ;)